# npm err ! unxepcter tocken occerd while installing react-native-cli

Tags: node.js, json, react-native, npm, npm-install

I'am trying to install react-native-cli but getting error

npm install -g react-native-cli

getting this error

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'react-native-cli' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.0
4 verbose npm-session 72c72ae6cf674a04
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-cli 247ms
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for react-native-cli@latest Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '<HTML><HEAD>
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData <meta h...'
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 568ms
11 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '<HTML><HEAD>
11 verbose stack <meta h...'
11 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
11 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
11 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
11 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
12 verbose cwd C:\Users\Basva
13 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
14 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "react-native-cli"
15 verbose node v10.15.0
16 verbose npm  v6.4.1
17 error Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '<HTML><HEAD>
17 error <meta h...'
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

What may be the wrong..!!!?

Comment: C:\Users\Admin>npm install -g react-native-cli
{npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '<HTML><HEAD>
npm ERR! <meta h...'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Basva\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-03T10_23_18_954Z-debug.log}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure whether your npm package correctly install.I solved this problem following below step.Try it..

1. npm i -g npm
2. npm cache clean
3. npm update
4. npm i

I think https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html is more useful for your.